# How do I convert a postgres 9.3 Slave to read-write without Impacting the Master

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a Postgres 9.3 Master-Slave stream replication setup on Ubuntu.
I would like to just convert the Slave into read-write by breaking the replication.  However, I do not want the Master to be impacted in any way, as its a critical *Production*.  All I want is to have a clone of the Master, so that I can test pg_upgrade.

Can I just run a "pg_ctl promote" on the slave, and open the Slave for read/writes?  Does running "pg_ctl promote" on the Slave have any impact on the Master?

Thanks very much.

Comment: yes - just run `pg_ctl promote` on slave. So it will stop reading from master. If you dont have cascaded replicas, that's it

Comment: Thanks. So looks like the Master would be not affected in any way. Would it impact a second Slave that is stream replicated from this Master?  Is using the recovery trigger file on the slave doing the same thing as a pg_ctl promote?

Comment: yes, promote and trigger_file are same - linked some docs in answer. Master will be released a little - the only affect. If second slave is streaming from master it wont notice other slave promotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby-failover.html):

> To trigger failover of a log-shipping standby server, run pg_ctl
>   promote or create a trigger file with the file name and path specified
>   by the trigger_file setting in recovery.conf. If you're planning to
>   use pg_ctl promote to fail over, trigger_file is not required.

so both `pg_ctl promote -D data_dir` and `touch trigger_file` promote slave equally. Master is affected by slave being promoted in sense that sender stops sending. Other slaves streaming from master are affected in same manner. Promoting is a standard action.

The only specific case [would be cascaded replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html):

> If an upstream standby server is promoted to become new master,
>   downstream servers will continue to stream from the new master if
>   recovery_target_timeline is set to 'latest'.

If you don't have any downstream "subslaves", promote it with courage.

Comment: Thanks Vao Tsun.  I ran the pg_ctl promote and it did not impact the production master or the 2nd slave.  I was able to upgrade successfully with pg_upgrade.